# PHP csv adding ₹ symbol instead of $

Tags: php, csv

I am using PHP to generate CSV file, I have stuck with the strange issue. I have attached $ symbol with a price but when I export CSV file. It shows Indian rupees symbol for those values which are less than 1000.

Please see attached images for more clarification.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get the same result if you escape it - `$price = "\$".number_format($price);` or use single quotes - `$price = '$'.number_format($price);`?

Comment: @Sean yes I am getting the same result as you have mentioned.

Comment: Change to `header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: I find it interesting that those are also the only values with a decimal value - `.00` - as well. Have you done a `var_dump()` on the original value and/or the final `$price` value before outputting?

Comment: When opening/importing the resulted CSV with Libre/MS Office, when format type do you select for the "Investment Cost" column? What if you select Text format there?

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.